# How to correct the missing citation counts/citing References in the Google Scholar?

Tags: citations, arxiv, physics, google-scholar, science

**How could we correct the missing citation counts and the missing citing References in the Google Scholar [suppose you have a Google Scholar profile](https://scholar.google.com/)?**

For example, I find that other resources such as https://inspirehep.net/ and http://www.adsabs.harvard.edu/ that links to arXiv may have much precise and better citation counts for a few particular publications of mine, while the Google Scholar misses many citation counts/missing citing References.

I am a physicist, an engineer, and a natural scientist. But I don't mind to receive comments from experts working in other disciplines.

Comment: Perhaps the best way is to stop worrying about it - while Google Scholar is nice, it is free so you get what you pay for...

Comment: You could write to them at scholar-support@google.com, stating your issue.